# What is the reverse word for abbreviation?

Tags: single-word-requests

An abbreviation is a shorter form of a word (or a phrase). This need not be unique. Suppose that one abbreviation for Engineering is ENG. Hence, we would say that the abbreviation of Engineering is ENG.

What would we call Engineering with respect to ENG? The "abbreviated word" does the job, but is there a more direct way of getting there? Say, the "unabbreviated"?

Comment: Hmm... Engineering is the word/the noun/the gerund, etc.; ENG is its abbreviation.

Comment: You’ve got it. The unabbreviated form or the “spelled-out” form is   “Engineering”.